# Error while using AWS dynamodb in VSCode debugger: operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, expect HTTP transport, got <nil>

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, vscode-debugger

I have a Golang codebase that connects to AWS using the `aws-sdk-go-v2` package. Here are my package versions:

```
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2 v1.18.0
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config v1.18.18
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue v1.10.19
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb v1.19.2
```

I have correctly placed my AWS credentials in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.
These credentials work fine with AWS CLI. The expected output is shown when I run:

```bash
aws s3 ls --profile <profile_name>
```

My `~/.zshrc` contains the env variable:

```bash
AWS_PROFILE=stage
```

---

## Problem

When I try to run the debugger in VSCode for the Golang project, the project builds and runs successfully. However, on every DynamoDB query, I get an error message:

```bash
operation error DynamoDB: Query, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, expect HTTP transport, got <nil>
```

**What have I tried?**

- I have rotated my AWS credentials
- I have updated all packages and sub-packages under `aws-sdk-go-v2` to their latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the integrated debugger of VSCode and not the AWS SDK or credentials. The `AWS_PROFILE=stage` written in my `~/.zshrc` used to load correctly until one day it stopped.

Since the AWS SDK was unable to determine which profile to use from the `~/.aws/credentials` file, it returned this error.

---

### Fix

Attach the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` in your launch configurations inside the `launch.json` file of VSCode to make sure this env variable is always available while launching the debugger/runner.

```json
{
    "name": "Run service",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    ...
    "env": {
        "CONFIG_SOURCE": "local",
        ...
        "AWS_PROFILE": "stage"  <---------- add this
    }
}
```